# Как сделать computed свойство внутри data объекта (VueJS)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
export default {
    computed: {
         'obj.prop': function() {
                return "bcad";
         }
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            obj: {
                 prop2: 2,
                 prop3: 3
                 //More
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Обращение к свойству obj.prop идет так как будто его не существует. При этом назвав свойство objprop всё работает корректно. Есть решение проблемы?
Свойство obj.prop - часть формы/модального окна или другой сложной структуры, при этом все остальные свойства - prop2/prop3 обычные, не computed

Comment: для computed нужно целое слово. Запись `'obj.prop'` - применима в watch

Comment: И группировать вычисляемые свойства тоже нельзя. А в чём необходимость делать такое вычисляемое свойство?